# Instagram Basic Display API oauth authorization from a pop-up

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, instagram-api

I’m developing a website where the user is able to get their Instagram media. I’m using the Instagram Basic Display API and a pop-up to do the authorization.
I’m using a tweaked code from here ([Get access token of instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117621/get-access-token-of-instagram-api)) and it is working more or less well.

The problem I have is when the user wants to connect a second time with a different Instagram account. Because the browser is already logged in to Instagram, the authorization doesn’t let to connect to a different account.
The only way is if the user logged out from Instagram manually from a different tab.

Has anyone face this problem before??

I would like to be able to let the user to fetch the media from different accounts without leaving my website. Does it make sense?

Thanks!

```
<script>
var accessToken = null;
var authenticateInstagram = function(instagramClientId, instagramRedirectUri, callback) {
    var popupWidth = 700,
        popupHeight = 500,
        popupLeft = (window.screen.width - popupWidth) / 2,
        popupTop = (window.screen.height - popupHeight) / 2;
    var popup = window.open(instagramRedirectUri, '', 'width='+popupWidth+',height='+popupHeight+',left='+popupLeft+',top='+popupTop+'');
    popup.onload = function() {
        if(window.location.hash.length == 0) {
            popup.open('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='+instagramClientId+'&redirect_uri=https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/instagram-oauth/&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code', '_self');
        }
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            try {
                if(popup.location.hash.length) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    accessToken = popup.location.search.split('code=')[1]
                    popup.close();
                    if(callback != undefined && typeof callback == 'function'){
                        callback(instagramClientId,instagramRedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(evt) {
                // Permission denied
            }
        }, 500);
    };
};

function login_callback(instagramClientId,instagramRedirectUri){

    data = {client_id:instagramClientId,client_secret:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",grant_type:"authorization_code",redirect_uri:instagramRedirectUri,code:accessToken}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url:"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/",
        data: data,
        success: function(response){

           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url:"https://graph.instagram.com/"+response.user_id+"/media?fields=media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url&access_token="+response.access_token,
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    //instaLogout()
                    //console.log(response);
                    $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {
                        if(v.media_type=="VIDEO") src_url = v.thumbnail_url
                        else src_url = v.media_url
                        $('#media').append("<img src='"+src_url+"' alt='' style='max-width: 300px'>")
                    });
                }
           });   
            
        }
    });
}


function login() {
    authenticateInstagram(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //instagram client ID
        'https://xxxxxxx.com/instagram-oauth/',
        login_callback //optional - a callback function
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aitor,  it may be worth showing your code, just in case your tweaks are relevant. Otherwise, I'd see if there is a function to show a "sign in as another account" function, or even show a logout button.

Comment: Hi Joshua!
What I'm asking it exactly that...how to do a "sign in as another account" function or a "logout button" from my website....because the Instagram Basic Display API doesn't have any way to do it.